# Connecting node with php

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I am new with node and I don't understand some things.... If when I use nodeJs I need to create server on localhost with some port like 3000 and my wamp server uses port 8080...

I am little confused how can I connect nodeJs code with php and mysql database? I don't know what to type for searching that.... Can I just make php file in program where I build node server like webstorm and in same folder-project where I have index.js etc to make like index.php and just add php code? But how can I connect it with wamp server for mysql database?

I asked this on yahoo answers, thenewboston, but no one answered, I know this website is not for this questions. But I need to know even if I get banned it is worth... Sorry for question and thanks for answers...

Comment: You won't be banned for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may be both server-side and can do a lot of similar things, but they're disjoint, so they can't directly communicate with each other, as far as I know.

If you're simply wondering how to connect NodeJS to a MySQL database, then you can use one of the nodejs modules: [node-mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) (quite simple - it should be enough for your needs), [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) or [node-mysql-libmysqlclient](https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient).

I've come across a situation where NodeJS is needed. The only possible communication between the PHP server and NodeJS was to use the PHP code to output something as HTML and then use jQuery's $ajax to send HTTP requests to an address where NodeJS is listening. So, the information goes from the PHP server to the client and then to the NodeJS page, where information can go back to the client if he has requested any. This can be risky if sensitive information needs to be sent between the two, but if the information is encrypted and the same encryption/decryption method is used on both PHP and NodeJS, it's safe.

Another way to connect them is to do this the other way round - when the user visits a NodeJS page, there can be an ajax query to a PHP page.

Another hypothetical way for them to communicate is them both accessing the database, although I haven't tried it and I'm not sure if no problems can't occur that way.

All in all, it depends on what the circumstances are and what you think would fit the most. There aren't any rules about how you have to "connect" your NodeJS code with your PHP code - you just use them as separate tools and pick the more suitable one for different jobs, making them "ask each other for help" if necessary. That asking for help is what the communication between them consists of.

Comment: I made some user website in php jquery ajax mysql, and for chat and search and other realtime request i want to use node... So what are you saying is that i need to make request for that purposes from jqeury to node like from my chat app I need to send request to node server t get my data? I was little confused when I start learning because I saw node creates its own server and I was like so i need to buidl whole website on that server. But I need that server only for request for getting data in realtime and sending it back to my php website or am I wrong?

Comment: @Don Sky Yes, the client-side script sends jQuery $ajax requests to the NodeJS server, asking it for data or sending it data. Don't worry about a whole NodeJS server having only the purpose of doing that. The situation where NodeJS was needed that I mentioned was when it was only used for notifications. (P.S. You don't really need NodeJS, because you can do this message thing with PHP. NodeJS may be faster than PHP, though, if many requests are being sent often, which should be the case with a chat. )

Comment: I did it with php but I have lot requests and it slows down thats why i want to use node

Comment: Good idea - it really is lightweight. I think you have to use Socket.io or a similar module (if another one exists) in order for the client-side script not to have to send HTTP requests to the NodeJS server every 2 seconds to check if there are any new messages in the chat. After all, socket.io is meant exactly for realtime apps. If you use socket.io, you won't need to use ajax requests.

Comment: Oh so i need to find now just how to use socket than :D thanks boy

Comment: @Don Sky I'm glad I helped, but just a warning - I'm not sure if socket.io won't consume too much CPU on the server if there are many users connected at once. It's quite tricky to use, too, because of the lack of adequate help and weird error messages. Personally, I'm still eager to use it myself because it's my best way to potentially make easily accessible web-based games. Anyway, good luck. | Now I found this - https://github.com/websockets/ws - which seems to be a lighter and simpler alternative to socket.io. You can research into it too if you'd like to.